# Bounty privilege

Tags: support

I am not able to see a "start Bounty" button on the question page, although the privileges page shows that i have this privilege. Please let me know how to start a bounty on a question asked by me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I suspect that the question isn't old enough. For your convenience I quote the relevant passage from the the [FAQ](https://math.stackexchange.com/faq):

---

**What if I don’t get a good answer?**

If, despite your best efforts, you feel questions aren’t getting good answers, you can help by offering a bounty. Slice off anywhere from +50 to +500 of your own hard-earned reputation and attach it to any question as a bounty. The bountied question will appear with a special indicator in all question lists, and it will also be visible on the home page Featured tab for the duration of the bounty period.

Click the bounty award icon next to each answer to permanently award your bounty to the answerer. There are a few other rules around bounties:

- Questions must be at least 2 days old to be eligible for a bounty.
- Users must have at least 75 reputation to offer a bounty.
- There can only be 1 active bounty per question and per user at any given time.
- Once initiated, the bounty period lasts 7 days.
- After starting a bounty, you must wait 1 day before awarding it.
- If you do not award your bounty within 7 days, the highest voted answer created after the bounty started with at least 2 upvotes will be awarded half the bounty amount.

In any case, you will always give up the amount of reputation specified in the bounty, so if you start a bounty, be sure to follow up and award your bounty to the best answer!

As an additional bonus, bounty awards are immune to the daily reputation cap and community wiki mode.

---

As a small additional tip: if you had added a link to your question here, you'd already have gotten a few curious people to look at the question you want to offer a bounty for.

Comment: thank you for the answer.